# DataTables yadcf Multi select filter Server Side Script

Tags: datatables, yadcf

I am using DataTables with Server Side and yadcf Multi select filter.

I have a database that I need to filter by multiple Caja ID, on the Database the Caja ID is just a number (1-30) i already did the yadcf_data_14 for the label and value of the filter.

The filter works almost good when i select 1 filter. If i Select Caja ID = 1 then i shows me all the items that has 1 and also 10 to 19 and 21. I am guessing it is a contains filter not exact value.
Also, when i select the second item to filter, then I shows Nothing.

I need help on getting the filter working when i select 1 to show me exactly the value selected, and when i select 2 filters then show me all the results of the 2 selected values.

Image with 1 Filter:
[image: 1 Filter]

Image with 2 Filter
[image: 2 Filter]

Comment: Your filter logic runs on the server-side, you should fine-tune it so it will return the results according to your needs

Comment: Can you tell me which part of the file I need to modify?

Comment: some php or java or any other language (depends on what you use)